# stopSerivce gives null object reference

Tags: android, service

I am trying to stop my service but it gives null object reference. this is my code ......

PendingUpdatesService.java

```
NetworkStateReceiver networkStateReceiver;
MarkAttendance attendance ;
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    networkStateReceiver = new NetworkStateReceiver(this);
    networkStateReceiver.addListener(this);
    this.registerReceiver(networkStateReceiver, new IntentFilter(android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

@Override
public void onNetworkAvailable() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "NW available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    SharedPreferenceSingleton.getInstance().init(getApplication());
    if (SharedPreferenceSingleton.getInstance().getIntPreference(StudentsAttendanceContracts.IF_ATTENDANCE_FAILED) == 1) {
        attendance = new MarkAttendance();
        attendance.updateAttendance(getApplicationContext());
    }
}

@Override
public void onNetworkUnavailable() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "NW not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

this is a class where i am trying to stop service......

MarkAttendance.java

```
String mClassId, mStaffId ;

String date, classAttendanceDate;
Context mContext;
SQLiteDatabase mDB;

public void updateAttendance(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    mDB = context.openOrCreateDatabase(DatabaseContracts.BLUEWINGS_STAFF_DB_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    SharedPreferenceSingleton.getInstance().init(context);
    mStaffId = String.valueOf(SharedPreferenceSingleton.getInstance().getIntPreference(SharedContracts.TEACHER_STAFF_ID));
    String[] parameter = {"Attendance"} ;
    String query = " SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseContracts.Tables.CheckingDataOnServer.TABLE + " WHERE " + DatabaseContracts.Tables.CheckingDataOnServer.MODULE_NAME + " =? ";
    Cursor cursor = mDB.rawQuery(query, parameter);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
        if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContracts.Tables.CheckingDataOnServer.IS_ATTENDANCE_SAVED)).equals("false")){
            mClassId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContracts.Tables.CheckingDataOnServer.CLASS_ID));
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
            classAttendanceDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContracts.Tables.CheckingDataOnServer.DATE));
            Date attendancedate = null;
            try {
                attendancedate = dateFormat.parse(classAttendanceDate);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            date = format.format(attendancedate);

            String[] parameters = {mClassId ,date + "%"};
            Cursor studentInfo = mDB.rawQuery(" SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseContracts.Tables.AttendanceTable.TABLE +
                    " WHERE " + DatabaseContracts.Tables.AttendanceTable.CLASS_ID + " =? " +
                    " AND " + DatabaseContracts.Tables.AttendanceTable.ATTENDANCE_DATE + " LIKE ? ", parameters);
            JSONObject attObj = new JSONObject();
            try {
                attObj.put(StudentsAttendanceContracts.FK_STAFF_ID, mStaffId);
                attObj.put(StudentsAttendanceContracts.CLASS_ID, mClassId);
                attObj.put(StudentsAttendanceContracts.ATTENDANCE_DATE, classAttendanceDate);
                JSONArray studentArray = new JSONArray();
                studentInfo.moveToFirst();
                while (!studentInfo.isAfterLast())
                {
                    JSONObject stuObj = new JSONObject();
                    stuObj.put(StudentsAttendanceContracts.STUDENT_ID, studentInfo.getString(studentInfo.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContracts.Tables.AttendanceTable.STUDENT_ID)));
                    stuObj.put(StudentsAttendanceContracts.ATTENDENCE_STATUS, studentInfo.getString(studentInfo.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContracts.Tables.AttendanceTable.ATTENDANCE_STATUS)));
                    studentArray.put(stuObj);
                    studentInfo.moveToNext();
                }
                attObj.put(StudentsAttendanceContracts.ATTENDANCE_KEY, studentArray);
                AsyncWorkerEncrypted mAsyncWorker = new AsyncWorkerEncrypted(context,false);
                mAsyncWorker.delegate = this;
                mAsyncWorker.execute(ServerConnector.MARK_ATTENDANCE, attObj.toString(), RequestConstants.POST_REQUEST, RequestConstants.HEADER_YES, RequestConstants.MARK_ATTENDANCE);


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
}

@Override
public void onRefresh() {

}

@Override
public void ReceivedResponseFromServer(String output, String REQUEST_NUMBER) {
    switch (REQUEST_NUMBER) {
        case RequestConstants.MARK_ATTENDANCE :
            Boolean response = false  ;
            try {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(output);
                response = obj.getBoolean(StudentsAttendanceContracts.RESPONSE_STATUS);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(response){
                String[] updateparameterOfCheckingPendingUpdatesTable = {"true", "Attendance", mClassId, date+"%"};
                String Updatequery = " UPDATE " + DatabaseContracts.Tables.CheckingDataOnServer.TABLE + " SET " +
                        "" + DatabaseContracts.Tables.CheckingDataOnServer.IS_ATTENDANCE_SAVED + " =? " +
                        " WHERE " + DatabaseContracts.Tables.CheckingDataOnServer.MODULE_NAME + " =? " +
                        " AND " + DatabaseContracts.Tables.CheckingDataOnServer.CLASS_ID + " =? " +
                        " AND " + DatabaseContracts.Tables.CheckingDataOnServer.DATE + " LIKE ? " ;
                mDB.execSQL(Updatequery, updateparameterOfCheckingPendingUpdatesTable);
                stopService(new Intent(mContext, PendingUpdatesService.class)) ;
                SharedPreferenceSingleton.getInstance().init(mContext);
                SharedPreferenceSingleton.getInstance().writeIntPreference(StudentsAttendanceContracts.IF_ATTENDANCE_FAILED, 0);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

enter code here

stopService(new Intent(mContext, PendingUpdatesService.class)) ;

for this line i am getting null object reference for context ....

this is my stacktrace

```
06-03 12:55:43.051 7714-7714/com.synclovis.bluewingsstaff E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.synclovis.bluewingsstaff, PID: 7714
                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.content.Context.stopService(android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference
                                                                            at android.content.ContextWrapper.stopService(ContextWrapper.java:539)
                                                                            at com.synclovis.bluewingsstaff.util.MarkAttendance.ReceivedResponseFromServer(MarkAttendance.java:119)
                                                                            at com.synclovis.bluewingsstaff.networkEngine.AsyncWorkerEncrypted.onPostExecute(AsyncWorkerEncrypted.java:178)
                                                                            at com.synclovis.bluewingsstaff.networkEngine.AsyncWorkerEncrypted.onPostExecute(AsyncWorkerEncrypted.java:26)
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Comment: startService i used in another class and its working properly.

Comment: Hows is `onNetworkAvailable` invoked?

Comment: still you have issue ?

Comment: i have a issue with stopService.........

Comment: @Raghunandan when network is not available that time  service will start, and when network is Available that time service will call onNetworkAvailable, and it calls MarkAttendance class where we save the cache data on server if that dat is not in server and then in Response i call stopService.

Comment: Please provide the stacktrace. It will offer more clues for us to help.

Comment: @Raghuveer i added stacktrace please check that

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `getApplicationContext()` with `this`.

Please provide the stacktrace which appears in your logcat when the exception occurs.

Comment: i added stacktrace , pleace check

Answer (score 0):

1. You are calling the ReceivedResponseFromServer method from the Async task.
2. It looks like updateAttendance() is where you would prefer to set the context.

It's hard to tell if it's a threading issue or something else, but a quick fix should be just passing in the context from the async task if you have access to it. That way you need not set the context in updateAttendance() as you're not using it in that method anyway (unless you're using it elsewhere in the class).

Comment: if iam not calling stopService my code is working perfectly. So, please tell me drawback of not stopping service

Comment: `getApplicationContext()` comes from the Service. You are passing a reference to this in `MarkAttendance.java`. `stopService()` destroys the service, thus taking the reference `mContext` now points to null. Prettty sure this is how you're getting the nullpointer exception.